# How to change the tolerance to get 8 significant numbers in the point fix method ( matlab)

Tags: numerical-methods, computer-science, matlab, numerical-calculus

So we have a fixed point function and were asked to choose an **epsilon ( tolerance)** that would give us an **approximation of the root with 8 significant numbers**.

The **root is 1** so we would like a result that gives us 1,234567 ( 8 significant numbers)

My question is how am i supposed to guess that ? I know we have the formula :

$\Delta x\leq  0.5\quad X \quad 10^-m $  (exponent -m) But i am not sure what plays the role of $\Delta x$ here i think it's $errel$ but i am not sure.

Also when i check the output in the console it's always  an answer with 5 significant numbers **no matter what** i change the epsilon to so i am a bit confused.

Thanks for your help.

**The function**

```
function [x] = pointfixe(g, x0, N, epsilon)

x(1)=x0;

x1=g(x0);

e_n=abs(x1-x0);
errel=e_n/abs(x1);

nbiterations=1;
while (errel > epsilon) & (nbiterations <N)
          x0=x1;
          x1=g(x0);
          e_n_1=e_n;
          e_n=abs(x1-x0);
          errel=e_n/abs(x1);
          nbiterations=nbiterations+1;
          x(nbiterations)=x1;
          disp(x);
end
end
```

**My script**

```
clear;close all;clc;

g1 = @(x) -0.25* (x^3 - 3*x^2  - 2);
x0 = 1.5;

epsilon = 1e-7;

N=50;

pointfixe(g1, x0, N, epsilon);
```

**A part of the console imput to show you an example about what i mean by 5 significant numbers**

[image]

**Edit from this output how can i analyze if the number of significant numbers is 8, how can i judge which epsilon will give me 8 significant numbers**

[image]

**New edit**

[image]

Comment: Have you tried 'format long'?

Comment: @Mape No i am new to matlab, where would i put that ? Thanks for reply.

Comment: Anywhere in the script, it will expand the numbers shown in the output. See https://se.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_env/format-output.html for more info

Comment: @Mape Ok yea this helps to show more significant numbers in the console, but i don't think it solves my problem since in the console even if i change the epsilon, my numbers always has the same significant numbers. I added an edit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are considering the functional iteration $$x_{n+1} = g(x_n)$$ where $$g(x) =  \frac{1}{4}(x^3 - 3 x^2  - 2)$$ and $x_0 = \frac{3}{2}$. You seek to recover the fixed point $x=1$ with a relative error which is less than $\tau = 10^{-8}/2$. We begin by considering the interval $I = [\frac{1}{2}, \frac{3}{2}]$ which contains $x_0$ and is centered around $x=1$. We have $$g'(x) = \frac{1}{4} (3x^2 - 6x) = \frac{3}{4} x (x-2).$$ A short calculations show that $|g'(x)| \leq \frac{3}{4}$ for $x \in I$. This shows that convergence sets in immediately and that we may choose $L=\frac{3}{4}$. You can now deploy the bound suggested by @PierreCarre, i.e.,
$$ |x-x_n| \leq \frac{L}{1-L} |x_n - x_{n-1}| = \frac{\frac{3}{4}}{\frac{1}{4}}|x_n - x_{n-1}| = 3|x_n - x_{n-1}|.$$
Since the target value is $x=1$ this observation allows you to bound the relative error. You need to iterate until $|x_n-x_{n-1}| \leq \tau$. As @PierreCarre correctly points out this analysis hinges on the choice of the function $g$.

Algorithms which attempts to detect convergence by monitoring $x_n - x_{n-1}$ can always be defeated by a sufficiently complicated function. Detail are presented in this [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1650403/307944) to a question related to the termination of Newton's method.

Comment: Thanks for reply, if you look at my last comment on Pierre post and which is related to my last picture in my post where i print the relative errors. It seems that i always come close to a value $xn-xn-1$ <= $T$  but the code always stop before because of the conditions. So i am kinda confused. Thanks And it seems to be like that for any N used and tolerance.

Comment: @codetime You are converging linearly as you should. Increase $N$ to about 65 to meet the required tolerance.

Comment: Ok idk what i don't understand but i never reach a number below  T am i looking the wrong thing let's say i choose N =65 and epsilon= 1e-8  i get a last relative error of 7.9234e-06. Just to show that no matter what i choose epsilon / 2 will always be smaller

Comment: @codetime I cannot replicate your problem. I have run function and your script without any problem. The fact that your current function underestimates the relative error by a factor of 3 is cannot explain why you get a relative error of $7.9234 \times 10^{-6}$. There must be some other problem.

Comment: mmm let's say i use epsilon = 1e-8 and N=58, my last errel printed will be 7.9505e-09 , no matter what i choose i will be above 0.5e-8 so i don't get it. What epsilon would u choose to get 8 significant numbers ? thanks again.

Comment: @codetime Your program thinks that the relative error is $1/3$ of the actual value. You want a relative error of $\frac{1}{2} \times 10^{-8}$, to get $8$ significant figures, so use $\epsilon = \frac{1}{6} \times 10^{-8}$. A good experiment would be to set $\epsilon=0$ and $N=200$. By examining the output you will be able to find the exact result for yourself. It can simpler to explain a result when you know it, than finding from scratch.

Comment: oh i thought i only had to play with the exponent... Maybe this is why i was so confused and didn't get the results i wante.. thanks..

Comment: @codetime Has the problem been resolved?

Comment: Yes, thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Keep in mind that no criteria will be independent of the particular function $g$. When you estimate the error by computing the difference between consecutive iterates (the abs(x1-x0) in your code), this is not an actual upper bound. What you can prove from the fixed point theorem (if the conditions hold) is that

$$
\underbrace{|x_n - z|}_{\textrm{error}}\leq \frac{L}{1-L} |x_n - x_{n-1}|.
$$

So you see that the difference $|x_n-x_{n-1}|$ is only an upper bound for the error if $L$ (the contractivity constant) is $\leq \frac 12$.

For instance, if $L=0.99$, you have that $L/(1-L) = 99$, so the actual error can be two orders of magnitude larger than the difference $|x_n-x_{n-1}|$.

That being said, since you are able to "sort of" estimate the error in each iteration, if you want to get $d$ significant digits, just iterate until the relative error is less than $0.5 \times 10^{-d}$.

note: Depending on the authors, the number of significant digits can be defined in terms of the relative error (I think this is more useful) or the absolute error.

Comment: Ok so if i understand i change the epsilon until my last relative error (errel) is less than $0.5X10^-d $ so it has nothing to do with the point fixe vector that i output ? I can just print errel and verify what is the last value and if it's less than 0.5 X...  if not i change my epsilon until it is. Do i understand this right ? Thanks a lot.

Comment: @codetime The output does not mean much... As others pointed out, it can even be a mater of formating in the displayed numbers. What is relevant is the estimated relative error. As you say, you just need to adjust epsilon to be $0.5 \times 10^{-d}$. But I stress the fact that this does not guarantee that you actually have d correct digits, unless you have an upper bound for L and replace one of the cycle conditions  according to the criteria in my answer.

Comment: ok i am not sure if i understand clearly, see my last added photo in the post. I obtain a last errel of 0.000 000  007 and my epsilon is exponent -8 so  $0.5X10^-8$ is 0. 000 000 005 and right now i am at 58 iterations ( N=58) and the program won't let me go above 58 because the condition is reached. So i am never able to be lower than $0.5X10^-8$ so there's something i don't understand thanks..